# Question on zero locus of holomorphic function.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I am trying to figure out a statement in Girffiths and Harris' book "Principles of Algebraic Geometry:

Given $f:U\rightarrow V$ a holomorphic map of open sets in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, and let $\mathcal{J}(f)$ be its Jacobian matrix.

If the zero locus of the holomorphic function $|\mathcal{J}(f)|$ is not empty, then it is "positive-dimensional"

What does this mean and why is this true?

As this comes before the definition of submanifold, I would appreciate if someone can help me without making any references to submanifolds.

Thanks!

Comment: We need $n > 1$; for $n = 1$, the zeros of the derivative are - unless $f$ is constant on some component - isolated points. For $n > 1$, a holomorphic function cannot have isolated zeros, and the zero set of a holomorphic function locally looks like a somewhat bent $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$ around generic points. Around some points, it looks like the union of finitely many bent $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$ intersecting there. For more precise descriptions, consult a book about Several Complex Variables.

Comment: Do you know any of the books which I can refer?

Comment: In alphabetical order, Grauert/Fritzsche, Gunning/Rossi, Hörmander, Kaup/Kaup, Krantz, Range are the ones I'm acquainted with; all good. Guessing, I think Grauert/Fritzsche or Range may be the best choice to start.

Comment: But I would still be interested if someone can explain in detail (like which theorem would be used) so that it saves me some time from reading :D

Comment: Page 40 of Grauert/Fritsche has the same theorem proved by showing the zero locus of a holomorphic function has at least one regular point.